# How do I clear the scan cache on my HP Deskjet F2238?

Tags: macos, scanner

I am trying to scan a document; the software indicates that I am scanning a new image (it shows the new image in the preview), so I know the scan function works but when I select 'Accept', the resulting file is a scan of a previous document. I've tried different things: adjusting the scan settings, turning on and off the scanner, but it still exhibits the same behavior.

I suspect that there's a temporary file somewhere that's not getting overwritten properly (my wife and I share a computer and she was using the scanner previously).

I am using MacOS X 10.5.8, HP Scan Pro, HP Deskjet F2238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebooted my MacBook and it's working again. I suspect that rebooting cleared some cached file that probably had permissions set differently.

I did some FSEventing and the files that are touched can be found in `/private/tmp`. They are:

- `ocrscan.jpg`
- `ICL`
- `RawFile.raw`
- `fma.tmp`
- `289_Scan`

All of these files except for fma.tmp get deleted once the scan finishes, so what probably happened was that one of these (probably `RawFile.raw`) wasn't getting deleted and the output was always the same.

Comment: For me, the file to delete was /private/tmp/save.raw

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some sort of factory reset procedure, when all else fails, uninstall the printer software and [reinstall the software](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=219&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3571756).

[Full User Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01438223.pdf)

Comment: As per the HP website: "The tool is not available for Mac OS X operating systems."